# How can i change file name while copying them using shutil?

Tags: python, shutil

I am using shutil to copy my files to another destination directory , what i want to achieve is

```
src/red.png
src/blue.png
src/green.png
```

for example if i select blue and green then while saving i want them to be saved as

```
dst/blue_1001.png
dst/green_1002.png
```

Thanks

Kartikey

Comment: Do you know how to construct strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to construct a destination path in a format that you want and `shutil` will do rest of the job.

I am using `pathlib` module here because it provides convenient APIs to work with paths.

```
>>> import shutil
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> 
>>> files_to_copy = ["src/red.png", "src/blue.png"]
>>> 
>>> destination = Path("dst")
>>> 
>>> for index, file in enumerate(map(Path, files_to_copy), start=1001):
...     destination_filename = f"{file.stem}_{index}{file.suffix}"
...     print(f"{destination_filename=}")
...     _ = shutil.copy(file, destination / destination_filename)
... 
destination_filename='red_1001.png'
destination_filename='blue_1002.png'
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it without using pathlib module tho ?

Answer (score 1):

Shutils supports setting the name of the target file. It mainly depends on how you splice the name of the target file

```
    import shutil
    from pathlib import Path
    parent_path = Path(__file__).parent
    file_path = parent_path.joinpath("test2.py")
    shutil.copy(file_path, parent_path.joinpath("test3.py"))
```